# What is the initial code for the string.split() function in python?

Tags: function, python-3.x, split

I want to know what the code is for the .split() function in python (simple way would be nice).
I am a newb to python and couldn't figure it out myself. Any help?

Edit: here's what I have so far...

```
stringInput =  str(input("Give me a string: "))

myList = []

firstPointer = 0

secondPointer = 0

for x in stringInput:

    secondPointer += 1

    if (stringInput[firstPointer] == chr(32)):#ASCII 32 is the space character

        stringInput +=1

        myList = stringInput[firstPointer, secondPointer]
```

Comment: I'm referring to string.split()

Comment: https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c#L1520-L1597

Comment: I know this isn't really question related, but ... you shouldn't really have to deal with pointers or worry about ascii characters too much. Python was made to be a nice friendly and easy language to use. It takes care of the messy stuff for you. Also it is based off of c, so some of the core functionality is optimized with c code and you want to use the basic python library instead of recreating it.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are doing this as a learning exercise.  *After* you have read the tutorial, imitating string methods is one way to learn.  .split is one of the harder ones.

```
s = '''This is a \tstring
to be    split'''
sl = []
i = None  # start of 'word'

for j, c in enumerate(s + ' '):
    if c.isspace():
        if i is not None:
            sl.append(s[i:j])
            i = None
    else:
        if i is None:
            i = j
print(sl)
# ['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'to', 'be', 'split']
```

Answer (score -3):

```
stringInput = str(input("Give me a string: "))

myList = stringInput.split()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods